# NameError: name 'synset' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, senti-wordnet, synset

From previous question, I get this code

```
print("Array..............\n\n")
tagged=np.array(df['tagged_texts'])
temp = []
for x in tagged: 
    for y in x: 
        temp.append(y) 
tagged = temp
print(tagged)
pos=neg=obj=count=0
for word, tag in tagged:
    ss_set = []
    if 'NN' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
        ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))
    elif 'VB' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
        ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    elif 'JJ' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
         ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    elif 'RB' in tag and swn.senti_synsets(word):
         ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
    if ss_set:
        pos=pos+synset.pos_score()
        neg=neg+synset.neg_score()
        obj=obj+synset.obj_score()
        count+=1
final_score=pos-neg
print(final_score)
df['final_score']=final_score
```

But then I get error message that name synset is not defined, anyone can explain to me why this happened? because I search the same question but I still didnt get to it

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-aa5a5112919f> in <module>
     11          ss_set = list(swn.senti_synsets(word))[0]
     12     if ss_set:
---> 13         pos=pos+synset.pos_score()
     14         neg=neg+synset.neg_score()
     15         obj=obj+synset.obj_score()

NameError: name 'synset' is not defined

​
```

Comment: I see no `import` statements at the top of your code. Is that because you indeed have none?

Comment: I used this ```from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn import pandas as pd
import numpy as np import nltk ``` did I miss something??

Comment: Since this is _your_ code, you would know better what `synset` is supposed to refer to.

Comment: I get this code and tried to figure whats wrong but still dont get it, I think the synset is to get the positive score, the code is tryin to calculate sentiment

Answer (score 0):

> `from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn`

Importing this module may solve this problem.

Comment: This won't actually load the symbol `synset` yet. OP would need to change `synset` to `wn.synset`, or maybe use `from nltk.corpus.wordnet import synset` if they really want the `synset` name as is.